# How to update a field in an embedded document in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

Please I need a orientdb sql query to update a field in an embedded document.
the Documents sample is like this

```
[

    {"id":"fd8ij14uc","text":"Option 1","votes":[]},
    {"id":"t44d32z73","text":"Option 2","votes":[]},
    {"id":"spceth23q","text":"Option 3","votes":[]}

]
```

**how do I add value like '#12:2' to the "votes" where "id":"fd8ij14uc"**

Comment: Hi, did you declare them as embeddedlist ?

Comment: Hi, could you give more details like your schema, ecc? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this structure :

```
create class Vote
create property Vote.vote integer

create class MyDocument
create property MyDocument.id String
create property MyDocument.text String
create property MyDocument.votes Linklist Vote

create class MyClass
create property MyClass.myField Embedded MyDocument

insert into vote(vote) values (25),(30),(31)
```

[image]

```
insert into MyClass content{"myField": {"@type":"d", "@class": "MyDocument","id": "fd8ij14uc","text": "Option 1", "votes": []}}
insert into MyClass content{"myField": {"@type":"d", "@class": "MyDocument","id": "t44d32z73","text": "Option 2", "votes": []}}
insert into MyClass content{"myField": {"@type":"d", "@class": "MyDocument","id": "spceth23q","text": "Option 1", "votes": []}}
```

[image]

```
UPDATE MyClass set myField.votes=[#12:0] WHERE myField.id="fd8ij14uc"
```

[image]